# How to prevent the abortion of html script on execution of node js program

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, webrtc, speech

What I'm trying to do: Real time speech to text conversion during a video chat

Using: Webrtc, web speech api, node js v9.9.0

What happens: index.html loads > the video element shows up appropriately with a button that begins speech to text on click > Button is clicked and speech to text works normally
BUT
when I open another tab, open localhost, the second video element also shows up appropriately next to the first, however, the speech to text aborted

Reason: Because there's another program with higher priority that starts executing. I'm guessing this other program is the node js program.

**What I need to know, is if there's a way the html script can continue executing even after the node js program, or whatever program is currently aborting it, begins its execution.**

I have tried using web workers in HTML but that just ended up not executing the speech to text script at all.

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Realtime communication with WebRTC</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: monospace;
      font-size: 22px;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />

</head>

<body>

  <h1>Realtime communication with WebRTC</h1>

  <span id="speech"></span>
  <span id="interim"></span>

  <div id="videos">
    <video id="localVideo" autoplay></video>
    <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay></video>
  </div>

  <script id = "STT">
    function upgrade() {
      alert('Please use Google Chrome for best experience');
    }
    window.onload = function() {
      if (!(window.webkitSpeechRecognition) && !(window.speechRecognition)) {
        upgrade();
      } else {
        var recognizing,
        transcription = document.getElementById('speech'),
        interim_span = document.getElementById('interim');
        interim_span.style.opacity = '0.5';
        function reset() {
          //recognizing = false;
          interim_span.innerHTML = '';
          transcription.innerHTML = '';
          speech.start();
        }
        var speech = new webkitSpeechRecognition() || speechRecognition();
        speech.continuous = true;
        speech.interimResults = true;
        speech.lang = 'en-US'; // check google web speech example source for more lanuages
        speech.start(); //enables recognition on default
        speech.onstart = function() {
            // When recognition begins
            recognizing = true;
        };
        speech.onresult = function(event) {
          // When recognition produces result
          var interim_transcript = '';
          var final_transcript = '';
          // main for loop for final and interim results
          for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
            if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
              final_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
            } else {
              interim_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
            }
          }
          transcription.innerHTML = final_transcript;
          interim_span.innerHTML = interim_transcript;
        };
        speech.onerror = function(event) {
            // Either 'No-speech' or 'Network connection error'
            console.error(event.error);
        };
        speech.onend = function() {
            // When recognition ends
            reset();
        };
      }
    };
  </script>

  <button onclick="STT">click</button>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

index.js:

```
   'use strict';

var os = require('os');
var nodeStatic = require('node-static');
var http = require('http');
var socketIO = require('socket.io');
var fs = require('fs');
var Connect = require('connect');
const threads = require('webworker-threads');


  console.log("in index.js");
  var fileServer = new(nodeStatic.Server)();
  console.log(' var fileServer = new(nodeStatic.Server)();' + fileServer);



var app = http.createServer(function(req, res){

  console.log("creating a server");
/*
    var worker = new threads.Worker(function(){
      function voiceRex(){
          console.log('at voiceRex');
          fs.readFile('./js/speechreg.html', function (err, html) {
            if (err) {
                throw err; 
            }
          });
            /*res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
            res.write(html);  
            res.end();
          }

          this.onmessage = function(event){
            res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
            res.write(html);  
          }
      });
      worker.onmessage = function(event) {
        res.end(); 
      };*/

    fileServer.serve(req, res);

}).listen(8000);
console.log('app:' + app);
var io = socketIO.listen(app);
console.log('io:' + io);


io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('io.sockets.on(connection, function(socket)');
  console.log('recieved connection ');
  // convenience function to log server messages on the client
  function log() {
    console.log('in log in index.js');
    var array = ['Message from server:'];
    console.log('message from server:' + array);
    array.push.apply(array, arguments);
    socket.emit('log', array);
  }


  socket.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log('Client said: ', message);
    log('Client said: ', message);
    // for a real app, would be room-only (not broadcast)
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', message);
  });

  socket.on('create or join', function(room) {
    console.log('Received request to create or join room ' + room);
    log('Received request to create or join room ' + room);



    var clientsInRoom = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[room];
    console.log(clientsInRoom);
    var numClients = clientsInRoom ? Object.keys(clientsInRoom.sockets).length : 0;
    console.log(numClients);

    log('Room ' + room + ' now has ' + numClients + ' client(s)');
    console.log('Room ' + room + ' now has ' + numClients + ' client(s)');

    if (numClients === 0) {
      console.log('number of clients is 0');
      socket.join(room);
      log('Client ID ' + socket.id + ' created room ' + room);
      socket.emit('created', room, socket.id);

    } else if (numClients === 1) {
      console.log('number of clients is 1');
      log('Client ID ' + socket.id + ' joined room ' + room);
      io.sockets.in(room).emit('join', room);
      socket.join(room);
      socket.emit('joined', room, socket.id);
      io.sockets.in(room).emit('ready');
    } else { // max two clients
      console.log('number of clients is max');
      socket.emit('full', room);
    }
  }, );

  socket.on('ipaddr', function() {
    console.log('in ipaddr');
    var ifaces = os.networkInterfaces();
    for (var dev in ifaces) {
      ifaces[dev].forEach(function(details) {
        if (details.family === 'IPv4' && details.address !== '127.0.0.1') {
          socket.emit('ipaddr', details.address);
        }
      });
    }
  });


});
```

index.html: With web worker

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Realtime communication with WebRTC</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: monospace;
      font-size: 22px;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />

</head>

<body>

  <h1>Realtime communication with WebRTC</h1>

  <span id="speech"></span>
  <span id="interim"></span>

  <div id="videos">
    <video id="localVideo" autoplay></video>
    <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay></video>
  </div>

  <script id="worker" type="javascript/worker">
var voice = function(transcription, interim_span){

var recognizing;
function reset() {
  //recognizing = false;
  interim_span.innerHTML = "";
  transcription.innerHTML = "";
  speech.start();
}

var speech = new webkitSpeechRecognition() || speechRecognition();
speech.lang = "en"; // check google web speech example source for more lanuages
speech.continuous = true;
speech.interimResults = true;
speech.start(); //enables recognition on default
speech.onstart = function() {
    // When recognition begins
    recognizing = true;
};

 speech.onresult = function(event) {
          // When recognition produces result
          var interim_transcript = '';
          var final_transcript = '';
          var interim_transcript_post = interim_transcript;
          var final_transcript_post = final_transcript;

          var final_transcript_post = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(final_transcript_post));
          // main for loop for final and interim results
          for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
            if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
              final_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
              final_transcript_post += JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(final_transcript));
            } else {
              interim_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
              interim_transcript_post += JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(interim_transcript));
            }
          }
          self.postMessage({

            'final_transcript_post': final_transcript_post,
            'interim_transcript_post': interim_transcript_post
          });
        };

        speech.onerror = function(event) {
          // Either 'No-speech' or 'Network connection error'
          console.error(event.error);
      };
      speech.onend = function() {
          // When recognition ends
          reset();
      };
      };

  </script>

  <script>

    var transcription = document.getElementById('speech');
    var interim_span = document.getElementById('interim');
    var transcription = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(transcription));
    var interim_span = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(interim_span));
    document.getElementById('interim').style.opacity = '0.5';


        var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('worker').textContent]);
        var w = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));

        w.postMessage({
          'transcription': transcription,
          'interim_span':interim_span


        });

         w.onmessage = function(event){

                transcription.innerHTML = event.data.final_transcript_post;
                interim_span.innerHTML = event.data.interim_transcript_post;


            };



  </script>

  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

[When one tab is open. speech to text works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIpFd.png)

[Two tabs are open and speech to text is aborted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdHjJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web speech api can not access microphone simultaneously with the video chat. If you want transcription inside video chat you should just stream the audio recorded to the external transcription service and display the results. Google Speech API supports streams for example, but it pretty expensive.